# FIRStorageErrorDomain, User does not have permission to access gs://

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload an image to my firebase storage however I am getting an error stating I do not have permissions yet I have an authenticated user already logged in.

Right before making the request to upload the image i am printing out the UID of the current user and this is printing and shows I am am currently authenticated.

The rules for accessing my storage are the same as my database and this same user has no issues reading and writing to the database so i dont know why it is not letting me write to storage:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

This is my code that I am using:

```
FirebaseUser user = await firebaseAuth.currentUser();
          print(user.uid);


          final StorageReference storageRef =
          FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(name + 'Logo.jpg');


          final StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(
            logo,
            StorageMetadata(
              contentType: 'image/jpg',
            ),
          );

          final StorageTaskSnapshot downloadUrl =
          (await uploadTask.onComplete);
          final String url = (await downloadUrl.ref.getDownloadURL());
          print('URL Is $url');
```

And the crash I am receiving is:

```
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Error -13021, FIRStorageErrorDomain, User does not have permission to access gs://*************.com/etetrLogo.jpg.)
```

When I remove the rules and allow read and write to all it is working but this is not a secure option. Any ideas anyone on how to get this working?

Comment: Did you ever solve this Callum? I'm having the exact same problem when I try to `getDownloadURL` immediately after a successful & authenticated upload.